# I am working with BLE in dart, where I need to send 9 bytes to the specific characteristic , where first byte is 5 and remaining is epoch

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8, bluetooth-lowenergy, epoch

Hi I trying to send 9 bytes to specific characteristic, where first byte is 0x05 , i.e 5 ,and next 8 bytes as epoch in seconds,

I tried this,

```
  List<int> timeDataForBLEWrite = [0x5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];  // here 0 will be replaced by 8 bytes of epoch
```

to get epoch in seconds, I tried this,

```
  int timestampEpochInSeconds = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000; // 1623331779
```

to convert epoch into bytes I have tried this,

```
 List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(timestampEpochInSeconds.toString());
```

but here I am getting 10 bytes because timestampEpochInSeconds  is 1623331779 // 10 digits

```
 print(bytes); // [49, 54, 50, 51, 51, 51, 49, 55, 55, 57]
```

how can I get 8 integers from the seconds epoch so that I can send total 9 bytes to the characteristic. like below,

```
 characteristic.write(timeDataForBLEWrite);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you don't want the string in bytes but the values in bytes.

Most data in Bluetooth is in Little Endian so I have made that assumption about the timestamp as bytes.

I did the following as an example on DartPad:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

List<int> epoch() {
  var timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
  var sendValueBytes = ByteData(9);
  sendValueBytes.setUint8(0, 5);
  // setUint64 not implemented on some systems so use setUint32 in
  // those cases. Leading zeros to pad to equal 64 bit.
  // Epoch as 32-bit good until 2038 Jan 19 @ 03:14:07
  try {
    sendValueBytes.setUint64(1, timestamp.toInt(), Endian.little);
  } on UnsupportedError {
    sendValueBytes.setUint32(1, timestamp.toInt(), Endian.little);
  }
  return sendValueBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
}

void main() {
  print('Epoch Bytes (plus 0x05): ${epoch()}');
}
```

Which gave the following output:

```
Epoch Bytes (plus 0x05): [5, 167, 60, 194, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hi ukBaz, I tried to 

write characterisitcs woth sendvalue , but it only take List<int> so I encoded it with

characteristic.write(sendValue.buffer.asUint8List()); 

below are the values of Read characteristics,

before sending bytes - [ 58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
after write - [ 5, 49, 171, 195, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
after read - [ 58 , 49 ]


I would need total 8 bytes from epoch , I am not sure if


  sendValue.setUint32(1, timestamp.toInt(), Endian.little);

will give 8 bytes , because when I print(sendValue.lengthInBytes); ///  i got 9 including (0,5) first index.

Comment: To convert an integer to 8 bytes you would use setUint64. This isn't implemented on the DartPad playground but as the value of the epoch will fit in to 4 bytes setUint32 was good enough. The `timeDataForBLEWrite` list is 9 bytes long as you can see the value printed out. What happens if you build the list manually with `List<int> timeDataForBLEWrite = [5, 167, 60, 194, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0];` and send that? Or send it as big endian ``List<int> timeDataForBLEWrite = [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 196, 69, 52];`?

Comment: Hi ukBaz, when I use setUint64 , I get only one byte in the 1 index , i.e out of 9 I have values in 0th and 1st Index, I the requirement I am requested to convert epoch to equal 8 bytes which gives total of 9 bytes including 5 in 0th Index

Comment: Please can you update the question with the code that you now have and any error messages you get. I don't understand why the code I posted in the answer works for me on https://dartpad.dev/ but it doesn't work for you

Comment: How do you convert it back to how it was? Basically, the question is How to convert the List<int> back to int?