# Equivalent function to struct.pack('<I', int) in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, struct

In both Python and JavaScript there is a function named `pack`

In JavaScript:

```
struct.pack('<I', 5311)
```

In Python

```
pack("<I", 5311)
```

Will result `[0, 0, 20, 191]` or `b'\x00\x00\x14\xbf'`.

Is there an equivalent function in dart?.

Comment: For people who aren't familiar with `struct.pack` in JavaScript or `pack` in Python, it would help if you described what you want instead.  Your example is also confusing since `14` and `bf` in hexadecimal aren't 242 and 115 respectively.

Comment: If you just want to write a 32-bit unsigned integer as a little-endian sequence of bytes, you can use [`ByteData.setUint32`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData/setUint32.html).  See [`dart:typed_data`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html) for related classes.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, the value 242 was wrong. 
I am not familiar with `struct.pack` myself and trying to convert Python code to dart.
Can you give example of how to use ByteData.setUint32 correctly?, I can't seem to understand how to do so `ByteData(0000).setFloat32(4, 5311)`

Comment: Many thanks @jamesdlin for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @GuyLuz Can you explain your final solution ?
I'm trying to convert python `struct.pack(">ii", 1, 1)` in dart.

Answer (score 0):

```
int timestamp = 5311;
var sendValueBytes = ByteData(8);

try {
  sendValueBytes.setUint64(0, timestamp.toInt(), Endian.little);
} on UnsupportedError {
  sendValueBytes.setUint32(0, timestamp.toInt(), Endian.little);
}

Uint8List timeInBytes = sendValueBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
timeInBytes = timeInBytes.sublist(0, timeInBytes.length - 4);

String inHex = '';
timeInBytes.forEach((element) {
  inHex += element.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0') + ' ';
});

print(inHex); // Will be: bf 14 00 00
print(timeInBytes); // Will be: [191, 20, 0, 0]
```

It is important to mention that int in dart is 8 bytes so to get 4 we need to remove it manually like I did with `.sublist`.

Credit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67922513/i-am-working-with-ble-in-dart-where-i-need-to-send-9-bytes-to-the-specific-char) in stack overflow.

Comment: And how do you convert it back? Like convert Uint8List back to int

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to pack or unpack values in dart, but code is a bit verbose.

It can be achieved using [dart:typed_data](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.4/dart-typed_data/dart-typed_data-library.html) and [dart:ffi](https://api.dart.dev/dev/3.0.0-319.0.dev/dart-ffi/dart-ffi-library.html) libraries.

1. Create your struct

```dart
@Packed(1) // To account for padding
class MyStruct extends Struct {
    @LongLong() // See NativeType class for complete list of available types 
    external int timestamp;
}
```

2. Allocate memory to your struct

```dart
const size = 8;
final pointer = calloc.allocate<Uint8>(size);
final struct = pointer.cast<MyStruct>();
```

3. Assign values

```dart
struct.ref.timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

4. Get the list of bytes

```dart
final bytes = pointer.asTypedList(size);
print('bytes $bytes');
```